# Angular Routing: can we pass component as router data?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

We have a common header section in our app where we show title and sub-title which are strings and stored in akita store.

Now in substring instead of string there we should display status, which is icon and we are using  component.

This is achieved by checking if the string includes any of status.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="isStatus; else strTemplate">
   <mat-icon>{{ subTitle }}</mat-icon>
<ng-container>

<ng-template #strTemplate>
  <span>{{ subTitle }}<span>
</ng-template>
```

I want to know is there any way we can avoid this checking and instead pass this component as router data and render as html.

something like

```html
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="subTitle"></ng-container>
```

I am asking this, because in future subtitle section can include different elements apart from these two.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check out this https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader
you can pass the name of the component   in the router and load it dynamic

Comment: also read this https://medium.com/ngconf/dynamic-component-generation-in-lazy-loaded-routes-d2e0f9e89c57

Comment: This was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you have data in your router in the `data` parameter, and you would like to access it. If that is correct, you can access that data in the `ActivatedRoute` Service. It would then look something like this:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  subTitle?: string;

  constructor(private readonly route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data?.subscribe(data=> {
      this.subTitle = data.subTitle;
    })
  }

}
```